# Cryptic errormessage from asp.net ajax updatepanel?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

Where to fix this errormessage?

> 41|error|500|Input string was not in a
>   correct format.|

I'm confused

Answer (score 1):

looks like server 500 error, line 41, with error message "Input string was not in a correct format", best to debug and break on all errors, assuming you are using VS you will break on the line of question

Comment: Agreed.  Debugging is a great approach for all AJAX related errors to see the line in question which may be causing the error.   The debugger should highlight it automatically once hit.

Answer (score 0):

Input string was not in a correct format is typically an invalid integer cast somewhere. Make sure in your update panel you're not sending an improper string to an integer cast.